# How to change the globale variables to local variables in C?

Tags: c, global-variables, local-variables

I am done with my assignment and everything works as I want but the thing is I am not allowed to have globale variables in this project therefor every thing should be in functions. Since I am new to C i don't really know how to get this work I mean How to change my global variables into local ones.

Appreciate Your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int tal[99] = { -1 };
int bubbles, byte, c, d, val;

/* Function for number gen*/
int talserie() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (c = 0; c < 100; c++) {

        tal[c] = rand() % 901;
        printf(" %d ", tal[c]);

        if ((c + 1) % 10 == 0)
            printf("\n");
    }
}
/* Funktion för bubble sort*/
int bubbel() {
    for (c = 0; c < (99); c++)
    {
        for (d = 0; d < 99 - c; d++)
        {
            if (tal[d] > tal[d + 1])
            {
                byte = tal[d];
                tal[d] = tal[d + 1];
                tal[d + 1] = byte;
            }
        }
    }

    for (c = 0; c < 100; c++) {
        printf(" %d ", tal[c]);
        if ((c + 1) % 10 == 0)
            printf("\n");
    }
}

/* Funktion för median-, max/min- och medelvärde*/
int varde() {
    printf("\nMaxvärdet är: %d", tal[99]);
    printf("\nMinvärdet är: %d", tal[0]);

    int total = 0;
    for (c = 0; c < 100; c++) {
        total = total + tal[c];
    }

    printf("\nMedelvärdet är: %d", total / 100);
    printf("\nMedianvärdet är: %d", ((tal[49] + tal[50]) / 2));
}

/*Funktion leta siffra*/
int siffra() {
    printf("\nSkriv in en siffra: ");
    scanf("%d", &val);
    d = 0;
    for (c = 0; c < 100; c++) {
        if (tal[c] == val) {
            d = 1;
            printf("\nFinns i talföljden på plats: ");
            if (c <= 9)
                printf(" Rad 1 och Kolumn %d\n", c + 1);
            else if (c > 9 && c <= 19)
                printf(" Rad 2 och Kolumn %d\n", (c + 1) - 10);
            else if (c > 19 && c <= 29)
                printf(" Rad 3 och Kolumn %d\n", (c + 1) - 20);
            else if (c > 29 && c <= 39)
                printf(" Rad 4 och Kolumn %d\n", (c + 1) - 30);
            else if (c > 39 && c <= 49)
                printf(" Rad 5 och Kolumn %d\n", (c + 1) - 40);
            else if (c > 49 && c <= 59)
                printf(" Rad 6 och Kolumn %d\n", (c + 1) - 50);
            else if (c > 59 && c <= 69)
                printf(" Rad 7 och Kolumn %d\n", (c + 1) - 60);
            else if (c > 69 && c <= 79)
                printf(" Rad 8 och Kolumn %d\n", (c + 1) - 70);
            else if (c > 79 && c <= 89)
                printf(" Rad 9 och Kolumn %d\n", (c + 1) - 80);
            else if (c > 89 && c <= 99)
                printf(" Rad 10 och Kolumn %d\n", (c + 1) - 90);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (d == 0);
    {
        printf("\n%d Finns inte i talföljden", val);
    }
}
/* Main funktion med switch meny*/
int main()
{
    while (val != 5) {
        printf("\n1. Generera en talföljd med 100 tal mellan 0-900.");
        printf("\n2. Sortera talföljden i storleksordning.");
        printf("\n3. Räkna ut medelvärde, median och maxvärde.");
        printf("\n4. Sök efter valfritt tal.");
        printf("\n5. För att avsluta\n");
        printf("Skriv in ett val (1-5): ");



        scanf("%d", &val);

        switch (val) {

        case 1:
            talserie();
            break;

        case 2:
            if (tal[0] == -1)
                printf("\nFel! Generera en talföljd först!\n");
            else
                bubbel();
            break;

        case 3:
            if (tal[0] == -1) /* Arrayen innehåller -1 i [0] innan talföljden genereras"*/
                printf("\nFel! Generera en talföljd först!\n");
            else if (tal[0] <= tal[1] && tal[1] <= tal[2] && tal[2] <= tal[3])

                varde();
            else
                printf("\nFel! Sortera talföljden i storleksordning först!\n");
            break;

        case 4:
            if (tal[0] == -1)
                printf("\nFel! Generera en talföljd först!\n");
            else if (tal[0] <= tal[1] && tal[1] <= tal[2] && tal[2] <= tal[3])
                siffra();
            else
                printf("\nFel! Sortera talföljden i storleksordning först!\n");
            break;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I speak in general, then you'll make the particular changes in your program.

Let's say that you use one of your global variables in the function `foo()`. If you want your variable to not being global anymore, then you need to pass it to `foo()` as one of its arguments.

So you would declare the variable as a local variable in the function that will call `foo()`

```
void caller( void )
{
    int local;
   
    foo( local );
}

void foo( int var )
{
...Some code...
}
```

That was a pass by value, if you need `foo()` to modify the variable then you need to pass by reference

```
void caller( void )
{
    int local;
   
    foo( &local );
}

void foo( int *pointerToVar )
{
...Some code...
}
```

EDIT: here an example to answer your comment. In main you will have

```
int main()
{
    int tal[99], c;

    talserie(tal, c);
    ...
}
```

And your function will be

```
talserie(int tal[99], int c)
{
    ...
}
```

But if you don't need to use `c` in main, you can declare it directly into `talserie` and you pass only `tal`

Comment: Yh I tried That but then I get errors while using the functions in switch. It says i have to write int function and after writing int i get error on int.

Comment: I put the return type `void` in my example, but you should put whatever you need to put.

Comment: Thanks for ur time but I dnt get it cuz I am quite new to programming and its my first time working with functions.

Comment: Maybe this can help you understand more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176118/when-is-it-ok-to-use-a-global-variable-in-c/176166#176166 and you seem to need clarification about passing and retuning arguments to function. Google those things

Comment: I tried to write my variables in to the function 
looks like this
void talserie(int tal[99], int c);
The in the main I have a switch where I used functions and by changing variables I get error on those functions. I tried to declare variables in main also but doesn't work.

Comment: Never mind got it fixed now. I forgot to write my variables into function parenthesis in main while using them for switch

Comment: @Masih MK I am glad you solved the problem. Anyway I wrote something more in the answer if you are interested

Comment: Thanks, It helped me figure out what I had to do.

Comment: Since I found your answer helpful, Would u mind taking a look into another question I asked? Its about the same assignment.

Comment: @MasihMK I did it :)